# Update record error when combined with delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a problem at the moment with my _form.html.erb for editing a game. My code for this class is as followed:

```
<%= form_for @game, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<% if @game.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@game.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this game from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @game.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
 <div id="p1"><%= f.label :game_name %> </div>
 <%= f.text_field :game_name %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="field">
 <div id="p1"><%= f.label :genre %> </div>
 <%= f.text_field :genre %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="field">
 <div id="p1"><%= f.label :console %> </div>
 <%= f.select :console, Game::CONSOLE_OPTIONS, :prompt => 'Select' %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="field">
 <div id="p1"><%= f.label :condition %> </div>
 <%= f.text_field :condition %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="field">
 <div id="p1"><%= f.label :description %> </div>
 <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 6 %>
</div>
 <%= f.file_field :photo %>
<br />
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 <%= button_to 'Destroy', root_url, :confirm => 'Are You Sure?', :method => :delete %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The problem I have is as followed. If I click the delete button it will delete the record no problem, but if I click the update button it removes the record also. If I take out the delete command then it updates fine. How can I get both to display together whilst doing their individual duties?

Comment: Make different forms that submit to different actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need extract your destroy button from your `form_for` of update.